# Fetch defined_names from a .xls file

Tags: python, excel, tagging

I'm trying to fetch tagged data from a `.xls` file.

I am able to fetch the tagged data from `.xlsx` file using `Openpyxl`, like this: `[dn for dn in wb.defined_names.definedName]`

But `openpyxl` does not support `.xls` format and I need to get the defined_names from `.xls` file as well.

Is there any library that can read .xls and return the defined_names in the file?

Answer (score 1):

check [xlrd package.](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Here is the relevant part of the docs - [Named references, constants, formulas, and macros](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references.html)

Comment: Thanks for the Reply! But this is not fetching all the user defined tags in the .xls. How can I fetch all the tags specified in a .xls using xlrd ?

Comment: Can you be more specific which names are not returned. There are example files provided. Note that names with scope worksheet are returned only for the current active/selected sheet (i.e. iterate over sheets to get all names with scope sheet)